# saving information as a variable in the middle of a series of pipes

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am trying to save some information about a intermediate file in a series of pipes. This information can be gleaned from the first few dozen lines, so ideally I would like to not process the entire thing twice.

The end result I want is a integer value stored as a variable that the script can then make use of for the next step.

What I have so far is

```
samtools bamshuf -Ou test.bam tmp | tee >($(eval READ_LEN=$(awk '{print length($10)}' | head -100 | sort -u))) | samtools bam2fq - | gzip -f > $OUT
```

Where I would like `READ_LEN` to contain the first sorted length of the first 100 lines of column 10 in the input file.

When I run this, I get no errors, but `READ_LEN` is not set. I assume this is because of the use of `eval`, and so stdout is not being piped on to `awk`.

How can I save information into a variable like this in the middle of a series of pipes?

Answer (score 2):

The variable READ_LEN is set in a sub-shell (because it is included in the "$(...).  When the sub-shell exits the variable is destroyed.  Capture the value and set the variable in the parent shell.  Something like

```
while read value; do
  [ -n "$READ_LEN" ] && READLEN+=" "
  READ_LEN+=$value
done < <(samtools bamshuf -Ou test.bam tmp | awk '{print length($10)}' | head -100 | sort -u)
```

Then use READ_LEN for the remainder of the processing